# Node.Js - return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to running NodeFuzz. The code was originally meant to run on Linux but I am trying to run it on MacOSX. The file is called Instrumentation.js
The code comes from this paper http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/nbnfioulu-201504161396.pdf 
Here is the code

```
var spawn=require('child_process').spawn
var fs=require('fs')
var browser={}
function cloneArray(obj){
 var copy = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
 copy[i] = obj[i];
 }
 return copy;
}
function saveResults(){
var testCases=cloneArray(config.previousTestCasesBuffer)
var time=new Date().getTime()
if(!fs.existsSync(config.resultDir+'/'+time)){
 fs.mkdirSync(config.resultDir+'/'+time)
 testCases.forEach(function(testCase,index){
 fs.writeFileSync(config.resultDir+'/'+time+'/'+index+'.html',testCase)
 })
 restartBrowser()
}
}
var startBrowser = function(){
browser = spawn(config.browserLaunchCommand, config.browserArguments)
}
function restartBrowser(){
browser.kill()
setTimeout(startBrowser,1000)
}
function handleFeedback(data){
console.log(data)
}
instrumentationEvents.on('websocketTimeout',saveResults)
instrumentationEvents.on('startClient',startBrowser)
instrumentationEvents.on('testCasesWithoutRestartLimit',restartBrowser)
instrumentationEvents.on('feedbackMessage',handleFeedback)
```

and here is the error

```
Loading default configuration-file:
./config.js
config.js had no property init.
Loading default instrumentation-module:
./Instrumentation.js
No module folder given. Defaulting to ./TestCaseGenerator.js from config.js
Found property init() from module ./TestCaseGenerator.js
Successfully required module ./TestCaseGenerator.js
We have 1 modules available.
Server listening port 1000
Tue Jun 21 2016 12:34:33 GMT-0400 (EDT): Feedback-loop initialized.
fs.js:794
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './results//1466526873714'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:794:18)
at EventEmitter.saveResults (/Users/greg/NodeFuzz/Instrumentation.js:15:5)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:166:7)
at null._onTimeout (/Users/student/NodeFuzz/nodefuzz.js:216:30)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Comment: looks like you have an extra "/" in the directory you are trying to create. may be a trailing slash in your config.resultDir, config.resultDir+'/'+time <- and you added another one here. mkdir works on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

replace all things that create paths by concatenation

for example `config.resultDir+'/'+time+'/'+index+'.html'`

with:

```
var path = require('path'); //at the top of the file
path.join(config.resultDir, time, index + '.html')
```

now you will be guaranteed to never have a double / in your paths, and as a bonus it will use the proper path separator for your OS (if you ever want to run this on windows too)

Comment: So replacing all things that create paths by concatenation will let the code run on MacOSX?

Comment: it will make it so you don't have invalid paths anymore, now, if the file isn't there its still not going to run.